# How to check a wcf service in Advance Rest Client or in POSTMAN

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Hi i have created a WCF service and want to check this service in "Advance Rest Client" but it was showing me the following responce.can any one suggest how we can check our service.
[image]

and here is the interface how i have written the code.

```
 public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        bool InsertData(Employee1 obj);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/ShowAll/")]
        List<Employee1> ShowAll();  

    }
```